# Android set dynamic image on Imagebutton

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

I want to set image dynamically on the ImageButton in android. However, I have more than 200 images. What would be the good solution for that?

The best idea is that I can use the name of image to call different images. i.e. imagebutton.setImage("/res/abc.png"); however, it seems to me that it is not trivial to do so.. please help me to solve these problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Typed Array](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray) resource. There is an example at the end of the link how to use it for drawables (images).

**Edited:**

Resources can be accessed as raw data: use [AssetManager.open(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open%28java.lang.String%29)
Then you can use [BitmapFactory.decodeStream(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream%28java.io.InputStream%29) to create a Bitmap from the data stream.

Comment: do you know how can i access images from drawable folder?

Comment: i mean not using R.id.XXX.png but like (res/drawable/xxx.png)?

Comment: drawable folder is inside .apk package and can not be accessed directly, except via resource methods

Comment: The example at the end of the link explains how to load image resources without explicitly addressing each one by it's name. Is there any other reason why you can not use this approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can take the images in your resource folder.  After that follow this simple code:

```
try {               
                Class<drawable> res = R.drawable.class;
                if(str!=null){                                   
                Field field = res.getField(str);
                int drawableId = field.getInt(null);
                bengalidaypng.setImageResource(drawableId);              
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                      System.out.println("Image not found in drawable folder");
            }
```

A more detailed sample can be found [here](http://www.androidcookers.co.cc/2012/01/set-image-dynamically-by-retrieving.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could store the images into a database, then [pull the images into the ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459729/how-to-display-list-of-images-in-listview-in-android/460927#460927) when you are binding each row.

Comment: then where should i put my images if there is no database?