# Android: Help add image to Private string

Tags: android, string

I have a class which holds strings.  I declared them like this:

private String pper[]={"" + "Juan", "Manuel",........};

This is then displayed as a listview, and that is fine.  Now, i want to add an icon/image on its item.  How can i do that?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are looking for that:
[How to display a list of images in a ListView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459729/how-to-display-list-of-images-in-listview-in-android)