# how to add different image to each raw in a LISTVIEW in Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, image, listview

i want to add to each raw a specific image that belong to each raw content in android listview...
example: if i am making a list view the countries and i want each country to have its flag ...
(example : 
(imageUSA-FLAG) USA
(imageUK-FLAG) UK
(imageFRANCE-FLAG) FRANCE
...

Answer (score 1):

You could do it for exampe like that:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   ImageView myImageView = new ImageView();  

   switch(position) {
      case 0: myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageUSA-FLAG);
      break;

      case 1: myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageUK-FLAG);
      break;

      case 2: myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageFRANCE-FLAG);
      break;
    }

    return myImageView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually searched before you posted then you would have found this [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459729/how-to-display-list-of-images-in-listview-in-android)