# attractive listview with images

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to build an application with a `listview` or whatever.. that looks very attractive and have some images and many more.But i cant find a good way to have that. I exactly want my application's `UI` like this images:

[image]
<sub>(source: [coenraets.org](http://coenraets.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/directory_plain_1.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [coenraets.org](http://coenraets.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/directory_plain_2.png))</sub>

i want to display my app like this images please suggest me how can i do this? please if u know some tutorials then give the links.

Comment: Check this example - [ListView with images and Text](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-asynchronous-image-loading-in-listview/)

Comment: This Tutorial Best Fits Your Requirnment http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Just place one `ImageView` and `TextView` in one xml layout. And, inflate this layout into one layout which is having the `ListView` And, do the process there for getting images from *webservice* or *locally stored*

Here i provide some example links that may very useful to you -

1. [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/541966/940096)
2. [ListView with images](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)
3. [How to display a list of images in a ListView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/459729/940096)

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the layout you want in a XML file, the same way you would do for an `Activity`. Then just inflate the XML layout for each row in your `ListView` and set its values and images.

Example of one ArrayAdapter that I've inflated with my own view (picture, text and checkbox):

```
private class FriendListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {

    public FriendListAdapter(Activity a, int textViewResourceId, List<User> items) {
        super(a, textViewResourceId, items);
    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        public TextView username;
        public ImageView image;
        public CheckedTextView ctv;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.invite_friend_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.username = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.username);
            holder.username.setTypeface(tf);
            holder.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.ctv = (CheckedTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.checked);
            v.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        final User user = getItem(position);
        if(user != null){
            holder.username.setText(user.getName());
            holder.ctv.setChecked(user.isChecked());
            holder.image.setImageView(user.getImage());
        }

        return v;       
    }
}
```

You get the idea!

Comment: can u provide me some examples .. coz i cant make it visually attractive. this images are of phonegap application.

Comment: what do you mean? have you already tried to implement this, if then make an edit and show code so I can see what the problem is?