# How to solve the following outof memory exception?

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I am working on Android and I am using Imagedownloader class to download the images and set to the image view in listview items sequentially.

But I am getting sometimes Outoffmemory exception when I am scrolling the list view continuously.

The exception is as follows.

```
   01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
   01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):  at       android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
   01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
   01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
   01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
  01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:618)
  01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:593)
  01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:445)
  01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
  01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1968)
  01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:677)
  01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):   at com.lt.appmedia.customise.SpeakersAdapter.getView(SpeakersAdapter.java:118)
  01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2197)
  01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1774)
  01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):   at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
  01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):   at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:636)
  01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):   at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5259)
  01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):   at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4467)
  01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
  01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
  01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
  01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
  01-28 15:30:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am unable to get an idea how to solve this.

The ImageDownloader Class is

```
public class ImageDownloader {

private final Map<String, SoftReference<Drawable>> mCache = new HashMap<String, SoftReference<Drawable>>();
private final LinkedList<Drawable> mChacheController = new LinkedList<Drawable>();
private ExecutorService mThreadPool;
private final Map<ImageView, String> mImageViews = Collections
        .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());

public static int MAX_CACHE_SIZE = 150;
public int THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 3;

private static ImageDownloader imageDownloader;


public static ImageDownloader shareInstance(){
    if(imageDownloader == null){
        imageDownloader = new ImageDownloader();
    }
    return imageDownloader;
}


/**
 * Constructor
 */
public ImageDownloader() {
    mThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
}

/**
 * Clears all instance data and stops running threads
 */
public void Reset() {
    ExecutorService oldThreadPool = mThreadPool;
    mThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
    oldThreadPool.shutdownNow();

    mChacheController.clear();
    mCache.clear();
    mImageViews.clear();
}

public void loadDrawable(final String url, final ImageView imageView,
        Drawable placeholder) {
    mImageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Drawable drawable = getDrawableFromCache(url);

    // check in UI thread, so no concurrency issues
    if (drawable != null) {
        // Log.d(null, "Item loaded from mCache: " + url);
        imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    } else {
        imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(placeholder);
        queueJob(url, imageView, placeholder);
    }
}

private Drawable getDrawableFromCache(String url) {
    if (mCache.containsKey(url)) {
        return mCache.get(url).get();
    }

    return null;
}

private synchronized void putDrawableInCache(String url, Drawable drawable) {
    int chacheControllerSize = mChacheController.size();
    if (chacheControllerSize > MAX_CACHE_SIZE)
        mChacheController.subList(0, MAX_CACHE_SIZE / 2).clear();

    mChacheController.addLast(drawable);
    mCache.put(url, new SoftReference<Drawable>(drawable));

}

private void queueJob(final String url, final ImageView imageView,
        final Drawable placeholder) {
    /* Create handler in UI thread. */
    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            String tag = mImageViews.get(imageView);
            if (tag != null && tag.equals(url)) {
                if (imageView.isShown())
                    if (msg.obj != null) {
                           imageView.setBackgroundDrawable((Drawable) msg.obj);
                    } else {
  //                               imageView.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
                        imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(placeholder);
                        // Log.d(null, "fail " + url);
                    }
            }
        }
    };

    mThreadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Drawable bmp = downloadDrawable(url);
            // if the view is not visible anymore, the image will be ready
            // for next time in cache
            if (imageView.isShown()) {
                Message message = Message.obtain();
                message.obj = bmp;
                // Log.d(null, "Item downloaded: " + url);

                handler.sendMessage(message);
            }
        }
    });
}

private Drawable downloadDrawable(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = getInputStream(url);

        Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, url);
        putDrawableInCache(url, drawable);
        return drawable;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

private InputStream getInputStream(String urlString)
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection connection;
    connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setUseCaches(true);
    connection.connect();
    InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();

    return response;
}
 }
```

and I am setting images to the ListView items by the following:

```
imageDownloader.loadDrawable(EventsListActivity.stylesheet.getBaseurl()+""+speaker.getPhoto(), imageView, mContext.getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.noimage ));
```

Comment: some time im also facing same problem than i can increase VM size for emulator and its work so u can try hope its use full for u

Comment: you are allocating too much `BitmapDrawable`s. you must free ones that you don't use at the moment (e.g. they're not currently in view). remember it is run on a mobile device with constrained memory.

Comment: @HCD you can't simply increase heap size on emulator and ignore the error. real devices don't have an option to increase heap size and you'll still get the exception. simply not on an emulator, but that's just hiding the problem, not resolving it.

Comment: you can try **LRUCache**... is very simple

Comment: than u write this code on your xml file android:largeheap="true" on application hope it will work definatly

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in `ImageDownloader`, but with your list.

When you create list with lots of images follow several steps:

1. Reuse items views. This is supported by adapter and easy to implement.
2. Do not save all images locally. If you bitmaps takes a lot of space you should release references to old ones, and let GC to collect them. Also do not forget about downloading them again when list scrolls back.

Answer (score 0):

Resources are constrained on a mobile device and this rears its head on Android especially when dealing with multiple images in list views such as this.

I would suggest:

1. **Investigate LRUCache** for caching your images to prevent having to download them again. You can find information about this here: http://android-er.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/caching-bitmaps-with-lrucache.html and here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html. It is also in the support library if you're targeting older platforms.
2. **Implement a List Adaptor** - that is what they're for. This way you're only using up resources to display visible images. There some good discussion on both this and downloading images here: [How to display a list of images in a ListView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459729/how-to-display-list-of-images-in-listview-in-android)
3. **Use Bitmpafactory** to downscale the image: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html - this will ensure you're not overallocating resources. Use only the dimensions / scale that you need.
4. When overriding the adapter class make sure you use LRUCache above and *first* **check to see if image is in the cache**, and if not, then download the image. This will speed up greatly the scrolling up instead of having to refetch the image.

Images are tricky resource hogs, but a tidy adapter, proper scaling/resampling and use of cache will make for a solid user experience without pesky out of memory errors.