# Using SVG files in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, svg, android-listview

Is it possible to use SVG files in ListViews (and if so, how?)

I've found some code that I can use to generate an ImageView and this works perfectly fine and loads up the required SVG Image

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.afghanistan);
imageView.setImageDrawable(svg.createPictureDrawable());
setContentView(imageView);
```

I'm just struggling to find a way of populating the ListView with SVG Images.  I'm populating my ListView in the code (example shown below)

```
private void populateShoppingList() {
shoppingList.add(new listItem("Apple", R.drawable.apple);
shoppingList.add(new listItem("Banana", R.drawable.banana));
shoppingList.add(new listItem("Grapes", R.drawable.grapes));
shoppingList.add(new listItem("Orange", R.drawable.orange));
}
```

Could anyone assist with ideas (or code) on how to get SVG files into the ListView?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an Adapter that can be used to populate your list with ImageViews.

There is an example of how to do this here: [How to display a list of images in a ListView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459729/how-to-display-list-of-images-in-listview-in-android)