# Display Images in Listview from sqlserver database into eclipse android

Tags: android, sql-server, android-listview

I can get only one pic from `Sqlserver` , Using this below code

```
rs= statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Addr1 where mobilenum=321");
blob = rs.getBytes(7);
```

I used below code to Display to `ImageButton`. It works.

```
 ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(blob);        
 bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);        
 images.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

How can I Get multiple images in `ListView` and Display ?
I Tried a lot...It Says Cant Display bitmap in listbox. Help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display a list of images in a ListView in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459729/how-to-display-a-list-of-images-in-a-listview-in-android)

Comment: @2Dee That link connects image with   R.drawable.image1 ( Drawable file )   But my code  deals with Image Bitmap